# Dropping all View under particular schema - SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to drop all views under particular schema.

Ex: if I got below views in db.

```
[dbo].[view1]
[dbo].[veiw2]
[dbo].[view3]
[myView].[view1]
[myView].[veiw2]
[myView].[view3]
```

I just want to drop all views under schema myView all at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 'drop view ' + QUOTENAME(sc.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(obj.name) + ';'
from sys.objects obj
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc
ON sc.schema_id = obj.schema_id
where obj.type='V'
and sc.name = 'myView';
```

Comment: Thanks AlSher it works.  Just changed sc.name = [myView] to sc.name = 'myView'

Comment: @Nev_Rahd: You should also keep in mind that this will break with names that normally need to be delimited. So, for safety, just replace `sc.name` and `obj.name` with `QUOTENAME(sc.name)` and `QUOTENAME(obj.name)` respectively.

Comment: If you have a lot of views, the select will truncate your string.

Answer (score 1):

I have tons of views (so, just aggregate drop query to one `nvarchar(max)` doesnt work - the query is truncated.) and i want to except some of views from deletion.

In this example, i want to drop every view from every schema beginnig with `usr_*` but not `usr_test`, `usr_usr`, `usr_usr1`, `usr_usr2` and `usr_usr3`.

`cursor` is used because i dont care about few ms. This view cleaning query is used before integration tests, its not really speed-critical (and yet it perform really well)

```sql
declare drop_view_cursor cursor for
  select 'drop view ' + QUOTENAME(sys.schemas.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(sys.views.name) + ';'
    from sys.views
    inner join sys.schemas on sys.schemas.schema_id = sys.views.schema_id
    where sys.schemas.schema_id in
    (
      select s.schema_id
        from sys.schemas as s
        where s.name like 'usr_%'
          and s.name not in ('usr_test', 'usr_usr', 'usr_usr1', 'usr_usr2', 'usr_usr3')
    )

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

open drop_view_cursor
fetch next from drop_view_cursor into @sql
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
begin
  exec (@sql)
  fetch next from drop_view_cursor into @sql
end

close drop_view_cursor
deallocate drop_view_cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

This takes into account Schema, uses the system tables, and outputs to a variable that may then be executed.  This way you don't have the problem of your Select truncating your script, because the Select and Print statements are limited on the length of what they may return.
The following runs in SQL Server 2008:

```
DECLARE @DropViewCommand nVarChar(MAX) = ''
 SELECT @DropViewCommand = @DropViewCommand
                        + 'DROP VIEW '+ QUOTENAME(S.Name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(V.name) + '; '
   FROM sys.views   as V
   JOIN sys.schemas as S
     ON S.schema_id = V.schema_id
  WHERE S.name = 'dbo'--Selectively delete by Schema.  Comment out to delete all views.
PRINT @DropViewCommand--See the command used in dropping all views (will be truncated in Select/Print, but not when Executing).
EXEC (@DropViewCommand)
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-posting [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13414944/2508781) for those looking for specific solution. Put DROP view code in WHILE loop as shown below:

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128) 
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)
DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(128)

SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'V' AND category = 0 ORDER BY [name]) 
SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.views WHERE [name] = @name)

WHILE @name IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
    SELECT @SQL = 'DROP VIEW [' + @schema + '].[' + RTRIM(@name) +']' 
    EXEC (@SQL) 
    PRINT 'Dropped View: ' + @name 
    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'V' AND category = 0 AND [name] > @name ORDER BY [name]) 
    SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.views WHERE [name] = @name)
END 
GO
```