# How to delete everything from a database (tables, views, stored procedures, functions)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to drop everything in the database, tables, views, stored procedures, and functions. I found some link but they don't work on complex database. It failed to drop tables. This is my own version of the script that I found on this website and tweak it.

```
/* Drop all non-system stored procs */ 
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128) 
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)
DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(128)

SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'P' AND category = 0 ORDER BY [name]) 
SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.procedures WHERE [name] = @name)

WHILE @name is not null 
BEGIN 
    SELECT @SQL = 'DROP PROCEDURE [' + @schema + '].[' + RTRIM(@name) +']' 
    EXEC (@SQL) 
    PRINT 'Dropped Procedure: ' + @name 

    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'P' AND category = 0 AND [name] > @name ORDER BY [name])
    SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.procedures WHERE [name] = @name) 
END 
GO 

/* Drop all views */ 
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128) 
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)
DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(128)

SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'V' AND category = 0 ORDER BY [name]) 
SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.views WHERE [name] = @name)

WHILE @name IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
    SELECT @SQL = 'DROP VIEW [' + @schema + '].[' + RTRIM(@name) +']' 
    EXEC (@SQL) 
    PRINT 'Dropped View: ' + @name 
    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'V' AND category = 0 AND [name] > @name ORDER BY [name]) 
    SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.views WHERE [name] = @name)
END 
GO 

/* Drop all Foreign Key constraints */ 
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128) 
DECLARE @constraint VARCHAR(254) 
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254) 
DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(128)

SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME) 
SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)

WHILE @name is not null 
BEGIN 
    SELECT @constraint = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND TABLE_NAME = @name AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = @schema ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME) 
    WHILE @constraint IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE [' + @schema + '].[' + RTRIM(@name) +'] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + RTRIM(@constraint) +']' 
        --BEGIN TRY        
            EXEC (@SQL)
            PRINT 'Dropped FK Constraint: ' + @constraint + ' on ' + @name
        --END TRY
        --BEGIN CATCH
        --  PRINT (@SQL)
        --END CATCH
        SELECT @constraint = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME <> @constraint AND TABLE_NAME = @name AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = @schema ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME) 
    END 
SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME) 
SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)
END 
GO 

/* Drop all Primary Key constraints */ 
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128) 
DECLARE @constraint VARCHAR(254) 
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254) 
DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(128)

SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME) 
SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)

WHILE @name IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
    SELECT @constraint = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND TABLE_NAME = @name AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = @schema ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME) 
    WHILE @constraint is not null 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE [' + @schema + '].[' + RTRIM(@name) +'] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + RTRIM(@constraint)+']' 
        IF @SQL LIKE '%PK_arrival_detail%' BEGIN PRINT @SQL END
        EXEC (@SQL) 
        PRINT 'Dropped PK Constraint: ' + @constraint + ' on ' + @name 
        SELECT @constraint = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME <> @constraint AND TABLE_NAME = @name ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME) 
    END 
SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME) 
SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)
END 
GO 

/* Drop all tables */ 
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128) 
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254) 
DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(128)

SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'U' AND category = 0 ORDER BY [name]) 
SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.tables WHERE [name] = @name)

WHILE @name IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
    SELECT @SQL = 'DROP TABLE [' + @schema + '].[' + RTRIM(@name) +']' 
    EXEC (@SQL) 
    PRINT 'Dropped Table: ' + @name 
    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'U' AND category = 0 AND [name] > @name ORDER BY [name]) 
    SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.tables WHERE [name] = @name)
END 
GO 

/* Drop all functions */ 
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128) 
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254) 
DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(128)

SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT') AND category = 0 ORDER BY [name]) 
SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.objects WHERE [name] = @name)

WHILE @name IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
    SELECT @SQL = 'DROP FUNCTION [' + @schema + '].[' + RTRIM(@name) +']' 
    EXEC (@SQL) 
    PRINT 'Dropped Function: ' + @name 
    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT') AND category = 0 AND [name] > @name ORDER BY [name]) 
    SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.objects WHERE [name] = @name)
END 
GO
```

The problem is only on the drop constraints and drop tables. It always failed with tables that have relationship to another table. How can I fix my script to make it works on more complex database?

Comment: Did you try "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;"

Comment: @ashiaka where can I set that? Remove the drop constraints and just set foreign_key_checks = 0?

Comment: it is a SQL-statement - use it as your first query (maybe it's only working for MySQL server)

Comment: How about dropping the database and creating a new one?

Comment: @RemusRusanu I cannot do that. :(

Comment: Take a backup of the empty database and then restore that?

Answer (score 10):

The script you provided is almost completed. I have adjust a few where condition here and there to make it more robust in complex case. This version is support delete 2 objects that have same name but difference schema. I also added a section to drop database trigger because it might prevent you to delete tables in some cases.

I have tested this with [AdventureWorks Databases](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/) and my own database (which somewhat very complex.)

```sql
    /* Drop all non-system stored procs */ 
    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128) 
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)
    DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(128)

    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'P' AND category = 0 ORDER BY [name]) 
    SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.procedures WHERE [name] = @name)

    WHILE @name is not null 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @SQL = 'DROP PROCEDURE [' + @schema + '].[' + RTRIM(@name) +']' 
        --PRINT (@SQL)
        EXEC (@SQL) 
        PRINT 'Dropped Procedure: ' + @name 

        SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'P' AND category = 0 ORDER BY [name])
        SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.procedures WHERE [name] = @name) 
    END 
    GO 

    /* Drop all database triggers */
    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128) 
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)

    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 T.name FROM sys.triggers AS T WHERE T.parent_id = 0 /* database trigger */ ORDER BY [name])

    WHILE @name is not null 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @SQL = 'DROP TRIGGER [' + RTRIM(@name) +'] ON DATABASE' 
        EXEC (@SQL) 
        PRINT 'Dropped TRIGGER: ' + @name 

        SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 T.name FROM sys.triggers AS T WHERE T.parent_id = 0 /* database trigger */ AND [name] > @name ORDER BY [name])
    END 
    GO 

    /* Drop all views */ 
    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128) 
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)
    DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(128)

    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'V' AND category = 0 ORDER BY [name]) 
    SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.views WHERE [name] = @name)

    WHILE @name IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @SQL = 'DROP VIEW [' + @schema + '].[' + RTRIM(@name) +']' 
        EXEC (@SQL) 
        PRINT 'Dropped View: ' + @name 
        SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'V' AND category = 0 AND [name] > @name ORDER BY [name]) 
        SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.views WHERE [name] = @name)
    END 
    GO 

    /* Drop all Foreign Key constraints */ 
    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128) 
    DECLARE @constraint VARCHAR(254) 
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254) 
    DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(128)

    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME) 
    SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)

    WHILE @name is not null 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @constraint = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND TABLE_NAME = @name AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = @schema ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME) 
        WHILE @constraint IS NOT NULL 
        BEGIN 
            SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE [' + @schema + '].[' + RTRIM(@name) +'] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + RTRIM(@constraint) +']' 
            BEGIN TRY
                EXEC (@SQL)
                PRINT 'Dropped FK Constraint: ' + @constraint + ' on ' + @name
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
                PRINT (@SQL)
            END CATCH
            SELECT @constraint = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME <> @constraint AND TABLE_NAME = @name AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = @schema ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME) 
        END 
    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME) 
    SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)
    END 
    GO 

    /* Drop all Primary Key constraints */ 
    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128) 
    DECLARE @constraint VARCHAR(254) 
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254) 
    DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(128)

    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME) 
    SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)

    WHILE @name IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @constraint = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND TABLE_NAME = @name AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = @schema ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME) 
        WHILE @constraint is not null 
        BEGIN 
            SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE [' + @schema + '].[' + RTRIM(@name) +'] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + RTRIM(@constraint)+']' 
            --PRINT @SQL
            EXEC (@SQL)
            PRINT 'Dropped PK Constraint: ' + @constraint + ' on ' + @name 
            SELECT @constraint = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME <> @constraint AND TABLE_NAME = @name AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = @schema ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME) 
        END 
    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME) 
    SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)
    END 
    GO 

    /* Drop all tables */ 
    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128) 
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254) 
    DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(128)

    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'U' AND category = 0 ORDER BY [name]) 
    SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.tables WHERE [name] = @name)

    WHILE @name IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @SQL = 'DROP TABLE [' + @schema + '].[' + RTRIM(@name) +']' 
        EXEC (@SQL) 
        PRINT 'Dropped Table: ' + @name 
        SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'U' AND category = 0 ORDER BY [name]) 
        SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.tables WHERE [name] = @name)
    END 
    GO 

    /* Drop all functions */ 
    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128) 
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254) 
    DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(128)

    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT') AND category = 0 ORDER BY [name]) 
    SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.objects WHERE [name] = @name)

    WHILE @name IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @SQL = 'DROP FUNCTION [' + @schema + '].[' + RTRIM(@name) +']' 
        EXEC (@SQL) 
        PRINT 'Dropped Function: ' + @name 
        SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT') AND category = 0 AND [name] > @name ORDER BY [name]) 
        SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.objects WHERE [name] = @name)
    END 
    GO 

    /* Drop all types */ 
    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128) 
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254) 
    DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(128)

    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sys.types WHERE is_user_defined = 1 ORDER BY [name]) 
    SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.types WHERE [name] = @name)

    WHILE @name IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @SQL = 'DROP TYPE [' + @schema + '].[' + RTRIM(@name) +']' 
        EXEC (@SQL) 
        PRINT 'Dropped type: ' + @name 
        SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sys.types WHERE is_user_defined = 1 AND [name] > @name ORDER BY [name]) 
        SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.types WHERE [name] = @name)
    END 
    GO
```

Comment: This is perfect. Even prints logs to see what was deleted !

Comment: After 5 years, it still works perfectly for me. But I didn't understand why this comment haven't been accepted since then.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer these links:
[Drop All Objects in a SQL Server Database](http://blog.falafel.com/blogs/AdamAnderson/09-01-06/T-SQL_Drop_All_Objects_in_a_SQL_Server_Database)

[List Schema Name and Table Name for Database](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/06/17/sql-server-list-schema-name-and-table-name-for-database/)

Comment: I had tried the script on the link you post but like I said, it does not work. It errors when it tried to drop constraints between tables.

Comment: How about building a query using `select * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS`? I haven't tried but.

Comment: I already did that as in my post. The problem is sometime it throws an error like 'xxx' is not a constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I would normally suggest the same approach as the other answer, but since that doesn't seem to be working for you, here's a whole different angle on it...

Generating the drop statements in the right order to get around the constraints is complex, but fortunately there's a whole niche market for schema modification tools to figure it out for you. Here's one approach that worked for me:

1. Create a blank database on a local SQL Server which uses the same version of SQL Server as the target
2. Download the trial version of [Red Gate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) (other similar vendor products may work too)
3. SQL Compare the local blank DB against the target DB, and run the script it generates for you

Again, not saying Red Gate is the only tool for it. Other vendors claim similar features, it's just that Red Gate is the one I use. Note also they have an [SDK](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-comparison-sdk/) if you're trying to embed this in some larger process or script.

Comment: I currently use Red Gate SQL Compare but the problem is the script files it keeps in TFS does not show any dependency. For example, if I have 10 views, 9 of them relate to 1 view, I have no idea which view I should execute first.

Comment: @Anonymous do you mean SQL Source Control? If you run SQL Compare interactively it gives you a single script to run (and it can even run it directly against the target)